# leave transition hook react router 2.3

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I am in the process of upgrading our react router from 0.13 to 2.3 however I am running into an issue.  In 0.13, to prevent the user from transition if say they have unsaved form changes, I would do this in the statics:

```
willTransitionFrom: function(transition) {
    if (unsavedChangesStore.hasUnsavedChanges()) {
        if (!confirm('You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave this page?')) {
            transition.abort();
        } else {
            this.props.dispatch(unsavedChangesActions.clearUnsavedChanges());
        }
    }
}
```

2.3 no longer uses the statics stuff.  From my reading, it seems like what I have to use is the `this.context.router.listenBefore()` however the only way I get the to work is by using a function like this:

```
function(location) {
    if (unsavedChangesStore.hasUnsavedChanges()) {
        return 'You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave this page?';
    }
}
```

The issue with this is that I need to be able to run cleanup code (`this.props.dispatch(unsavedChangesActions.clearUnsavedChanges())`) if the user clicks ok to make the transition and loss the changes.

How can I accomplish the `willTransitionFrom` does in 0.13 in 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact scenario your code puts you in, here's a stab at it:

In ES6:

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    this.context.router.setRouteLeaveHook(
      this.props.route,
      this.routerWillLeave
    )
  }
  routerWillLeave( nextLocation ){
    if (unsavedChangesStore.hasUnsavedChanges()) {
        return 'You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave this page?';
    }
  }
  render(){
    return <h1>The Page</h1>
  }
}

Page.contextTypes = { router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired }
```

OR in ES5

```
var Page = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired    
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
   this.context.router.setRouteLeaveHook(
      this.props.route,
      this.routerWillLeave
    ) 
  },
  routerWillLeave( nextLocation ){
    if (unsavedChangesStore.hasUnsavedChanges()) {
        return 'You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave this page?';
    }
  },
  render:function(){
    return <h1>The Page</h1>
  }
});
```

Comment: The issue is that from what I see with `setRouteLeaveHook` and `listenBefore` (and `setRouteLeaveHook` gives a warning about using `listenBefore` instead) I have no ability to execute custom code depending on if they click to continue or not (and this would need to be custom depending on what page it happens on so I would not be able to set generic code on the `browserHistory`).